# from 【txt】write in excel2007,In CMD print in right sequence, but the excel file data didn't in right sequence

Tags: excel, python-3.5, openpyxl

openpyxl-2.5.0a1    python 3.5

from 【.txt】write in excel 2007,In CMD print in right sequence ,but the excel file data didn't in right sequence.

here my code:

```
import openpyxl

loadActive = open('F:\\pythoncode\\ActivityList.txt', encoding="utf-16")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('F:\\pythoncode\\example_1.xlsx')

dataActive = loadActive.readlines()

sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()
c = []
for i in range(len(dataActive)):
    c += dataActive[i].split('\t')

j = 1
columnNum = 1
for i in range(int(len(c))):
    if i < 3:
        sheet.cell(row = j,column = columnNum).value = c[i]
        columnNum += 1
    else:
        if i % 4 == 0:
            j += 1
            columnNum = 1
            sheet.cell(row = j,column = columnNum).value = c[i]
            print(sheet.cell(row = j,column = columnNum))
            print(c[i])
        else:
            sheet.cell(row = j,column = columnNum).value = c[i]
            columnNum += 1
            print(sheet.cell(row = j,column = columnNum))
            print(c[i])

loadActive.close()
wb.save('F:\\pythoncode\\example_1.xlsx')
```

txt file data:

```
Id  ActivityId  TimeDesc    Remark
int_cs  int_c   string_c    string
note    Actid   timessss    memo
1   2   9:00-9:40   hello1
2   13  10:00-10:40 hello2
3   43  11:30-11:45 hello3
4   22  12:00-14:00 hello4
5   43  12:30-12:45 hello5
6   2   15:00-15:40 hello6
7   13  16:00-16:40 hello7
8   43  17:30-17:45 hello8
9   22  18:00-20:00 hello9
10  43  18:30-18:45 hello10
11  25  20:15   hello11
12  23  20:30-20:45 hello12
13  1   20:45-21:15 hello13
```

---

this is the writhed in excel didn't in right sequence

[image: [1]]

print in cmd in right sequence

[image: [2]]

Comment: I think it must the '\n' in list. Then I writing in excel. It's wrong.But I don't know how to delete the last '\n'. I had try so many times and ways to solve it.I didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import openpyxl

loadActive = open('F:\\pythoncode\\ActivityList.txt', encoding="utf-16")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('F:\\pythoncode\\example_1.xlsx')
# ' '.join(ActiveList)

dataActive = loadActive.readlines()

print(dataActive)

sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()
c = []
#this loop to solve the \t and \n      

 for i in range(len(dataActive)):
    c1 = dataActive[i].rstrip('\n')
    c += c1.split('\t')
    print(c[i])
print(c)

j = 1
columnNum = 1
for i in range(int(len(c))):
#delete simplified the logic
    if i % 4 == 0:
        j += 1
        columnNum = 1

    sheet.cell(row = j,column = columnNum).value = c[i]
    columnNum += 1

loadActive.close()
wb.save('F:\\pythoncode\\example_1.xlsx')
```

another problem: There will imported an empty first line